Degree of an immersion defined on a ''graph manifold''
Degree of immersion
Let the immersion $h$ be such that
$$h:z\equiv(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*}\longrightarrow{}Z\equiv(X,Y)
\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*+} ,$$
where
$$X=x-y^2-3/4 ,\qquad{}Y=x-1-(x-y^2-3/4)^2 \,,$$
Then, the Jacobian determinant $h$ is: $\det(J(h))=2\,y$ .  And therefore $\det(J(h))>0$ on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*}$ , and orientation is preserved by $h$ .
Moreover, given $X$ and $Y>0$ , we get:
$$x=X^2+Y+1 ,\qquad{}y_{\pm}=\pm \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{4(X^2-X+Y)+1} \,.$$
Let the maps $k_+$ and $k_-$ be such that
$$k_\pm:Z\equiv(X,Y)
\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*+}\longrightarrow{}z_\pm\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*\pm} \,,$$
where
$$z_\pm=\Big(X^2+Y+1 \,,\, \pm\,\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{4(X^2-X+Y)+1}\,\Big) \,.$$
The pullback of the volume form $dX\wedge{d}Y$ by $h$ should be:
$$h^*(dX\wedge{d}Y)=2 \,y \,dx\wedge{d}y \,.$$
Note $\mathcal{M}\equiv(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*})\times(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*+})$ .
Now, let the manifold $G(h)$ (the ''graph manifold'') be such that
$$G(h)=\Big\{(z,Z)\in\mathcal{M} \:\:/\:\: Z=h(z) \big\} \,,$$
and the immersion $$H: (z,Z)\in{}G(h)\longrightarrow{Z}\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*+} \,.$$
Then, there are two points $z_+$ and $z_-$ given $Z$ . So, if $V\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*+}$ is a relatively compact open neighborhood of $Z_0\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*+}$ , then $H^{-1}(V)=U_+\cup{}U_-$ , where $U_+$ is an open neighborhood of $(z_{0,+},Z_0)$ and $U_-$ is an open neighborhood of $(z_{0,-},Z_0)$ . Since $H$ is proper, then $U_+$ and $U_-$ are also relatively compact open neighboordhoods.
So, if we consider two coordinate charts on $U_+$ and $U_-$ , one: $(z_+\equiv(x,y_+>0),Z)$ on $U_+$ , and the other one: $(z_-\equiv(x,y_-<0),Z)$ on $U_-$ , should not be written on $U_-\cup{}U_+$ (or subsidiary question $U_-\times{}U_+$ ?):
$$H^*(dX\wedge{d}Y)=2\, y_- \,dx\wedge{d}y_- +2\, y_+\, dx\wedge{d}y_+ \,?$$
Or, use a partition of the unit:
$$H^*(dX\wedge{d}Y)=2\, \rho_-(Z)\, y_-\,dx\wedge{d}y_- +2\, \rho_+(Z)\, y_+\,dx\wedge{d}y_+ \,?$$
where $\rho_\pm$ are positive smooth functions defined on a relatively compact open $O\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{*}$ containing $k_-(V)\cup{k}_+(V)$ and such that 1) $\rho_+$ equals 1 on ${k}_+(V)$ and $\rho_-$ equals 1 on ${k}_-(V)$ , and 2) $\rho_+(z)+\rho_-(z)=1$ on $O$.
Morever, how could be defined the degrees  of $H$ on $H^{-1}(V)$ and $h$ on $V$ in this case because we might ''formally'' have:
$$H^*(dX\wedge{d}Y)\equiv\deg(H)\,(dx\wedge{d}y) \,,$$
and
$$h^*(dX\wedge{d}Y)\equiv\deg(h)\,(dx\wedge{d}y) \,?$$

Degree is not defined locally, but rather, globally. Certainly when you pull back a volume form you do not get an integer multiple of "the" volume form. Indeed, degree is not generally defined in a non-compact setting.

Yes, that's what I knew, which is why I took relatively compact open neighborhoods. And I restrict the maps to these neighborhoods. These would be the degrees of these restricted maps. But I was wondering if finally the notion of degree is related to the number of pre-images, which in this case would be 2 on these neighborhoods (up to the orientation between the two-dimensional manifolds which could be the same making the substitution  $Y\to -Y$ preserving the sign of $Y$). And therefore also the question of the partition of the unit if I don't make this restriction to these neighborhoods.

In one book, a proof is presented in which differential forms are taken to have compact supports contained in open neighborhoods and if the fundamental classes are cohomologous. These open neighborhoods could be a common open neighborhood for all these differential forms.

Therefore, if $H^2(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^*)\simeq{H}^2(V)$ no partition of the unit would be necessary. It would only be necessary in the absence of the above equivalence?
